# cyrillic character escaping problem on RAILS JSON + EXTJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, extjs

I have a problem with the escaping of the cyrillic characters in the rails JSON output:

```
{"success":true,"total":"2","offices":[{"address":"addr","created_at":"2011-06-03T11:55:09Z","description":"desc","id":1,"name":"Office 1","published":true,"updated_at":"2011-06-05T13:48:35Z"},{"address":"\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd","created_at":"2011-06-03T12:32:19Z","description":"\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd","id":2,"name":"\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd 2","published":null,"updated_at":"2011-06-05T13:49:51Z"}]}
```

They are not properly decoded in EXTJS and result in grid is �������� 2

The page encoding is UTF8. Mysql and Rails configs are set to UTF8

Any ideas ?

Comment: Which ruby and which rails version?

Comment: I can confirm this issue. With same version of rails and ruby, all non-ascii letters are written like \ufffd (including the Swedish "ÅÄÖ" and Cyrilic "ЯЧЩ"). I have isolated the issue to the to_json function.

Answer (score 0):

Any code?
All I see is that your characters already distorted in json output (they're all the same, if you take a closer look - "\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd").

Comment: yes after a while I also notice that, the output is generated with the following code
[code]
def index
.........
@offices = Office.find(:all, :conditions => buildFilterOptions(params[:filter]),   :limit => gf_limit, :offset => gf_offset, :order => gf_sortcol + ' ' + gf_sortdir)
    
render :json => {:success => true, :total => gf_total.to_s, :offices => @offices}
end
[/code]

Comment: Try to add response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'; before your render.

Comment: the problem is the mysql gem and the solution is explained here: [link](http://gnuu.org/2009/11/06/ruby19-rails-mysql-utf8/)

10x to everyone